# ClassNotFoundException in java networking?

Tags: java, exception, networking, serialization, chat

I am writing a multi-threaded java chat application, I am getting a Class Not Found Exception when I send a MessageStructure object over the network to the server side.

Server Side:

```
@Override
public void run() {

    while(true)
    {
        try {
            MessageStructure message=(MessageStructure)input.readObject();
            ServerSocket.ProcessIncomingMessage(ThreadId, message);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ChatServerThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ChatServerThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
```

Client Side:

```
  public void SendMessage(MessageStructure message)
{
    try {
        output.writeObject(message);
        output.flush();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ClientSideSocket.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nu.connect.client.MessageStructure
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:622)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1593)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1514)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1750)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
at nu.connect.server.ChatServerThread.run(ChatServerThread.java:56)

public class MessageStructure implements Serializable{
public String MessageType;
public String reciever;
public String sender;
public String message;

public MessageStructure(String MessageType, String reciever, String sender, String message) {
    this.MessageType = MessageType;
    this.reciever = reciever;
    this.sender = sender;
    this.message = message;
}
```

}

Comment: Does the server side code have that class?

Comment: yes it does have that class.

Comment: That's not what the classloader is saying. Make sure the class is there, at runtime, on the classpath.

Comment: I don't have a default constructor can that be an issue?

Comment: No, deserialization doesn't need to use a constructor (it's magic). The stacktrace is clearly telling you "the class doesn't exist on the classpath". If you ignore this clear message, I can't help you further.

Comment: Yes you are right, I can think I copy pasted the class from client to server side. Thanks for your help, should learn how to read the stack trace properly.

Comment: That is an important skill to practice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the stack trace carefully, especially this line :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nu.connect.client.MessageStructure
```

What you have here is a scenario where the MessageStructure class does exist, but it's in a different package in your server code. You might want to redesign your code so that the same package is used on both sides, that will make it possible for Java to find your class.

Comment: I copy pasted the classes in Netbeans is probably the reason for this error.

Comment: I think all of us have been bitten by the Copy & Paste zombie.  Don't worry, this is a good learning opportunity, being able to read stack traces is a good skill!

Comment: Hard to find a powerful IDE like visual studio in the Java paradigm.

Comment: I work in Visual Studio quite a lot and yes, NetBeans and Intelli-J, as well as Eclipse are different, but I find all three being extremely powerful and productive.  It might be that with Visual Studio, there's mostly just one way of doing something, the .Net way, but with Java, you have so many options and choices, which makes tooling harder to develop. Just look at all the ORM tools we have compared to the poor .Net guys :P